# How to display a page that tells the user they are being redirected before redirecting them in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using JavaScript to get a device number and use that to create a url. From there the user is redirected to the website. I wanted to create a simple HTML page that displays a message for a few seconds letting the user know if they are being redirected, and if they are unable to redirect the user shows an error message.

I appreciate any help you advise you can give me.

````
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import './Welcome.css'


import config from './apiConfig' // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

let counter = document.querySelector('h1')
let count = 1

setInterval(() => {
  counter.innerText = count
  count++
}, 1000)

const Welcome = () => {
  const fetchLocationAndRedirect = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        'apiurl'
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data.location_id)
        var location_id = res.data.location_id
        //Create new url
        const myURL = new URL('https://' + location_id + '.com')

        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
          // browser code
          window.location.href = myURL // Redirect user to my website
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    //alert('foo')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLocationAndRedirect()
  }, [])

  return <h1 style={{ float: 'center' }}>Now redirecting you to My Website</h1>

}

export default Welcome```
````

Comment: How does the current behavior differ from the desired behavior?

Comment: @RockySims Right now it doesn't redirect to the URL anymore. It just showcases in plain html "Now redirecting you to My Website" from the return statement at the end.

Comment: `'apiurl'` is clearly a placeholder... I assume it's not `'apiurl'` in your actual code, is it?

Comment: What does `console.log(res.data.location_id)` show in the console?

Comment: Yes that's correct I am using an internal API and I cant post it.

Comment: ```console.log(res.data.location_id)``` was me checking to see if my API call successfuly retrieved the devices number, I needed the device id to make the create the URL

Comment: And does it successfully retrieve the device number? What exactly does `console.log(res.data.location_id)` show in the console?

Comment: @RockySims Yes it successfully retrieve the device number. In the console it just printed out the device number. Before I added the <h1> the file redirecting worked

Comment: It really looks like it should work... what if you comment out all the code in `fetchLocationAndRedirect` and instead put `console.log('redirecting to google'); window.location.href = 'https://google.com';`? Does it start redirecting successfully? If not, does the "redirecting to google" console message show up at all?